# Symfony Load Twig Template For Email

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

I got error in symfony twig template during load.

Do I need to include this : use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

**[InvalidArgumentException]**

`Unable to find template "CrudBundle:email.html.twig".`

**[Twig_Error_Loader]**

`Unable to find template "CrudBundle:email.html.twig".`

**[Twig_Error_Loader]**

```
Unable to find template "CrudBundle:email.html.twig" (looked into: C:\xampp
\htdocs\sample\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resourc
es/views/Form).
```

This is the folder structure.

`src/Btn/CrudBundle/command/SystemCommand.php` : Class location

`src/Btn/CrudBundle/Resources/views/email.html.twig` : Template location

```
class SystemCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {

        $this
            ->setName('cron:email:send')
            ->setDescription('Verifies that accounts');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln("This is a test");
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('sample@sample.com')
            ->setTo('sample@sample.com')
            ->setBody(
                $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render(
                    'CrudBundle:email.html.twig',
                    array('name' => $staffer->getUser())
                )
            )
        ;
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);          
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add second colon to the template name. CrudBundle::email.html.twig. You also can simply use $this->render instead of $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render

Answer (score 2):

Try `CrudBundle::email.html.twig` instead of `CrudBundle:email.html.twig`.